# How can I wait if it's not possible in smart contracts?

Tags: contract-design, tokens, erc-20, timestamp, block-interval

From my understanding, waiting in a solidity smart contract would create a total disaster for the whole Ethereum's blockchain.

I can see in some circumstances that solidity offers block.timestamp and keywords such as "now + 1 day".

My specific scenario is the following:

A smart contract sends an ERC20 Token from 3 different addresses. However,
those tokens shall not be sent at the same time, but eventually wait between
1 minutes and 1 hour between each transaction.

Is that achievable using smart contracts?

Comment: would that require to call the transaction 3 different times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most use-cases can be solved by inverting control. Rather than having the contract run something at a certain time, interested parties claim entitlements when appropriate. The contract decides if the requests are permissible.

So, a delayed entitlement would go:

1. Buyers sends ETH. Contract records future entitlement to tokens. When (not before) and how much.
2. Buyers claims token. Contract checks entitlement and performs a little accounting to prevent double-claims.

Other patterns can solve for large batch jobs such as calculating dividend entitlements without resorting to scheduled tasks.

Hope it helps.